# Import function from another python file, but use definitions from original file

Tags: python, import

Say I have file1.py and file2.py, and inside file2.py I have func2() but it uses variables and definitions made exclusively in file1.py...how can I import and call func2() in file1.py, without throwing "NameError: name 'dependency1' is not defined"?

file2.py:

```
def func2():
    print('do something cool')
```

file1.py:

```
# here I import and define a bunch of things, e.g
from module1 import dependency1

from file2 import func2
func2()
```

Comment: This is not a proper design. A module should not depend on the module that imports it.

Comment: You should move your dependencies around so that there are no cycles. Make it into a hierarchy.

Comment: understood...but how can I import code that I don't want written in file1, from file2? There are things in file1 that need to stay there.

Comment: this is for mobile automation testing, and file1 holds the class that sets up the test. and I don't want this in all the modules I import. so I thought of just importing the functions separately into the main file1.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simple answer is that you can't. What you are trying to do is use a circular reference, which is why your implementation is breaking. File2.py is referencing variables from file1.py, which is referencing a function from file2.py.

Not to mention the bad coding convention, but it would also be a nightmare to develop further from here if anything were to break.

Long story short: do yourself a favor and work on some encapsulation. Make each file able to function on their own, and then you can do some importing for your final product.

edit: That in a test bench I was able to get file2.py to run, but not file1.py. This is still not your intention, but I wanted to point it out so you are not confused. Regardless, it would still be better to just do yourself the favor and separate out your files.